# ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=4 "The request was cancelled

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, asihttprequest

The below function is not downloading the content from server and it gives ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=4 "The request was cancelled.

This function is called from viewdidload.but the same urls are working fine and **it is downloading the content fine in the -(void)downLoad:(id)sender event:(id)event function but not in the -(void)startDownload function.**

Please let me know what is the problem / wrong thing in my function (-(void)startDownload)

**below function is working fine**

```
-(void)downLoad:(id)sender event:(id)event{

self.tblViewDownload.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

IsRequestCompleted = NO;

CGPoint touchPosition = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.tblViewDownload];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblViewDownload indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPosition];
UITableViewCell *Cell = [self.tblViewDownload cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

progress = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
progress.frame = CGRectMake(65, 55, 210, 25);
progress.progress = 0.0;
[Cell.contentView addSubview:progress];

UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
button.hidden=YES;

if(!self.networkQueue)
    self.networkQueue = [[[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init] autorelease];

[self.networkQueue cancelAllOperations];
[self.networkQueue setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueCompleted:)];
[self.networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
[self.networkQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:progress];

[self.networkQueue setDelegate:self];

NSDictionary *aDict =[self.myUrlArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSString *aImgUrl = [aDict objectForKey:@"IMG_URL"];
NSString *aVideoUrl = [aDict objectForKey:@"VIDEO_URL"];
NSString *aAudioUrl = [aDict objectForKey:@"AUDIO_URL"];

NSArray *aPoemArrayUrls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aImgUrl,aVideoUrl,aAudioUrl,nil];

for(NSString* urlString in aPoemArrayUrls)
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    ASIHTTPRequest *downloadAFileRequest = [[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url]retain];
    NSString *Filename = [urlString lastPathComponent];
    NSLog(@"%@ filename",Filename);
    [downloadAFileRequest setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"request1" forKey:@"name"]];
    [downloadAFileRequest setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:Filename]];
    [downloadAFileRequest setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
    [downloadAFileRequest setDelegate:self];
    [downloadAFileRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
    [downloadAFileRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
    [downloadAFileRequest setShowAccurateProgress:YES];

    [self.networkQueue addOperation:downloadAFileRequest];
    //----
}

[self.networkQueue go];

}
```

**The below function is not working and gives ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=4 "The request was cancelled**

```
-(void)startDownload{

if([self.myUrlArray count] > 0 ){

int count = [self.myUrlArray count];

int i = count - count;

NSLog(@"%d iiiiii",i);

NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];

UITableViewCell *Cell = [self.tblViewDownload cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];

progress = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
progress.frame = CGRectMake(65, 55, 210, 25);
progress.progress = 0.0;
progress.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[Cell.contentView addSubview:progress];

  if(!self.networkQueue)
      self.networkQueue = [[[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init] autorelease];

  [self.networkQueue cancelAllOperations];
  [self.networkQueue setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueCompleted:)];
  [self.networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
  [self.networkQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:progress];

  [self.networkQueue setDelegate:self];

  NSDictionary *aDict =[self.myUrlArray objectAtIndex:[myIP row]];
  NSString *aImgUrl = [aDict objectForKey:@"IMG_URL"];
  NSString *aVideoUrl = [aDict objectForKey:@"VIDEO_URL"];
  NSString *aAudioUrl = [aDict objectForKey:@"AUDIO_URL"];

  NSArray *aPoemArrayUrls = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aImgUrl,aVideoUrl,aAudioUrl,nil];

  for(NSString* urlString in aPoemArrayUrls)
  {
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
      ASIHTTPRequest *downloadAFileRequest = [[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url]retain];
      NSString *Filename = [urlString lastPathComponent];
      NSLog(@"%@ filename",Filename);
      [downloadAFileRequest setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"request1" forKey:@"name"]];
      [downloadAFileRequest setDownloadDestinationPath:[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:Filename]];
      [downloadAFileRequest setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
      [downloadAFileRequest setDelegate:self];
      [downloadAFileRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
      [downloadAFileRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
      [downloadAFileRequest setShowAccurateProgress:YES];

      [self.networkQueue addOperation:downloadAFileRequest];
  }

  [self.networkQueue go];


}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to set `IsRequestCompleted = NO;` in the second function.  Also, why are you sending cancelAllOperations?  That has a great chance of being the problem.

Also, there is no need to autorelease `self.networkQueue` and reinitialize it every time.  Just set it once for the class and release in `-dealloc`.

Comment: Also bad idea adding directly to cell [Cell.contentView addSubview:progress]; Reusing will break your logic

Comment: Agreed NeverBe, didn't catch that one.